# My laptop Dell XPS 13 has only one USB port

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, dvd

Will I be able to connect an external USB DVD±RW that needs two?

I also have an external hard drive that needs two USB ports. I briefly connected it and it seemed to work but I didn't do enough transfers to be sure.

Comment: No;  If the device needs a USB port for data and a USB port for power then it cannot function on a single USB port.  What you can do is get an externally powered USB HUB and connect the device to that.

Comment: At this age you propably have a USB loading plug for the wall. If not, get a USB HUB like @Ramhound suggests.

Answer (score 1):

If a device uses two USB connections, the most likely reason why it does so is because it needs more power than a single USB connection is guaranteed to be able to provide (and possibly more than a single USB connection is spec'd to *be able* to provide).

Recording CDs or DVDs is also a power-hungry operation, which further supports the hypothesis that the device needs more power than a single USB connection can provide. (For the burner, you need power for both the drive motor and the laser on high power. The external HDD has similar needs.) I don't know the exact figures, but this comes out to a relatively significant amount of power; an internal HDD can easily need up to 10 W or thereabouts, while standard USB 2.0 is only specified to be able to supply 2.5 W (after high-power negotiation).

Your best choice is probably to get a quality, powered USB hub and connect through that. Doing so will ensure that you can connect the devices in the manner intended by the manufacturer. Trying to jury-rig solutions that draw the current from the single USB port is likely to lead to problematic operation or outright failure, either in operating (the devices in some manner failing to perform their respective task) or in the worst case could possibly damage the hardware itself.